# How to place icons in proper way so it will work perfectly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My icons are coming fine in simulator, when i run on actual device 6s plus then lock icon are hidden.I attached both screens.Please give me right suggestion.
    In simulator 6s plush width coming 414.I'm using this below code.

```
if (WIDTH==414) {
    cell.txtFld_Category.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, WIDTH/2, 47.5);
}
else {
    cell.txtFld_Category.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, WIDTH/2 + 20, 47.5);
}
cell.txtFld_Category.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0f; 
[cell.txtFld_Category setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kFontRegular size:18.0f]];
cell.btn_Edit.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(cell.txtFld_Category.frame) + 16, 10, 24, 25);  btn_EditTransp.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(cell.txtFld_Category.frame), 0, 47, 47); 
btn_Locked.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(btn_EditTransp.frame) + 10, 4, 35, 35);
btn_Lockedtransp.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(btn_EditTransp.frame), 0, 47, 47);
```

Here is the image on simulator

[image]

Device image here

[image]

Comment: did u subclassed the tableview cell ... ?

Comment: How are you defining `WIDTH`?

Answer (score 0):

If u subclassed the tableview cell, (u are not mentioned in the question that, how u are creating the tableview cell),if u are not, then subclass the tableview cell, name it as `CustomTableViewCell` for example.

in `CustomTableViewCell.m` file override `layoutSubviews` method, like below

```
//cell creation 
+ (CustomTableViewCell *)cell
{
    NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
   if ([arrayOfViews count] < 1) {
      return nil;
   }
   for (id item in arrayOfViews) {
    if([item isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        return item;
   }
return nil;
}

//initial set up 
- (void)awakeFromNib {
   // Initialisation code
   [self.txtFld_Category setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kFontRegular size:18.0f]];
   self.txtFld_Category.layer.cornerRadius=9.0f;
    }

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    if (WIDTH==414)
    {
     self.txtFld_Category.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, WIDTH/2,47.5);
    }
    else {
    self.txtFld_Category.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, WIDTH/2+20,47.5);
    }

    self.btn_Edit.frame=CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(cell.txtFld_Category.frame)+16,10,24,25);
    btn_EditTransp.frame=CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(cell.txtFld_Category.frame),0,47,47);
    btn_Locked.frame=CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(btn_EditTransp.frame)+10,4,35,35);
    btn_Lockedtransp.frame=CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(btn_EditTransp.frame),0,47,47); 
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is why you should use AutoLayout. Add a constraint to the right border of the screen.

Comment: Thanks, Actually i'm not using Auto layout.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are not adding any constraints to your UITableView. Adding a few simple pins to the table view, such as pinning it 0 points from the top, bottom, leading, and trailing margin should do the trick.